# Can htaccess check if file exists on a url or external server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ftp, server

Can .htaccess check if a file exists on another server or a url?
I want to use .htaccess to check if file exists on storage server then do the rewrite condition.

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/i%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

If I change to

```
RewriteCond http://external.example.com/i%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

It wont work. I store my files on a separate server and would need to check it on the web server because of lack of space. Is there a way to make it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The `-f` attribute test treats the TestString as a *pathname* and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file (see the `-f` section in [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)). As such, this attribute test, much like `-d`, is a file system test and cannot test files on a remote server.

As mentioned above, the test treats the string as a *pathname*, which is a sequence that identifies a file on a file system. The pathname always starts from your root directory or from the current working directory. As such, the pathname *cannot* include references to an external host, such as `external.example.com`. See the *pathname* definition [here](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/pathname.html).

Comment: As far as I am aware, there isn't. It would be nice if one could do a sub-request to check if the 200 response code is sent, indicating the requested path represents an existing resource. You would be better off just referencing the external server directly.